# convert comma separated adjacency list into 2-column edgelist (to build igraph object)

Tags: r, igraph

I searched a lot through stackoverflow's wealth of information to find a solution but I am stuck ! I am learning R and igraph by reading and doing, so please bear with me if the question is too simple :)

I have been using this below code to extract text data (adjacency list) of co-authorships from google scholar profile pages, and I wanted to turn it into co-authorship networks, but I was not successful in using graph_from_adjlist in Igraph; it was not building network in the right way, so I changed my approach and tried to turn them into edgelist first and then use more common graph_from_edgelist function, I found a solution [here](http://igraph-help.nongnu.narkive.com/eEtzrBmG/adjacency-list-to-edgelist); it works fine when the number of rows (in my case publications) are less than 300, but for more than that it gives this error in R:

```
Error in rep(x[1], length(x) - 1) : invalid 'times' argument
Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> Q
```

Honestly I don't know the logic of the code in turning columns of adjacency list to 2-column edgelist and I was unable to find out what is wrong.

Here is my small bit of code (I have described each step in inline comments):

```
library(scholar)
library(igraph) 
# one scholar profile link (works fine with small number of authors)
scurl <- "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=nG42BMAAAAAJ&hl=en"
# prof Welman google scholar link as an example that gives the above error
# scurl <- "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=_q2NODAAAAAJ&hl=en"
citid <- strsplit((strsplit(scurl,"&",fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]),"=",fixed = TRUE)[[1]][2]
# authors <- as.data.frame(cSplit(subset(get_publications(citid,flush = TRUE),select = "author"),splitCols = "author",sep = ",")) ## this I put to check if authors are extracting in a right way
pub <- get_publications(citid,flush = TRUE)
coauthors <- as.character(tolower(pub$author)) ##to make text differences less effective in result
adjlist=strsplit(coauthors,",") # splits the character strings into list with different vector for each line
col1 <- unlist(lapply(adjlist,function(x) rep(x[1],length(x)-1))) # establish first column of edgelist by replicating the 1st element (=ID number) by the length of the line minus 1 (itself)
col2 <- unlist(lapply(adjlist,"[",-1)) # the second line I actually don't fully understand this command, but it takes the rest of the ID numbers in the character string and transposes it to list vertically
edgelist <- cbind(col1,col2) # creates the edgelist by combining column 1 and 2.
coauthorgraph <- graph_from_edgelist(edgelist,directed = FALSE)
set.seed(333)
coauthorgraph$layout <- layout.circle
tkplot(coauthorgraph)
```

I tried to add a (times=400) condition to the col2 line, but it didn't help.
 I will be really grateful to hear any piece of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One column is each element minus the first, the other column is the first element repeated the length of the vector - 1.  You can get that with `rep(..., times=lengths(adjlist)) - 1L`.  So, picking up after you get `pub`,

```
## tolower does character conversion, and remove the trailing "..."
coauthors <- sub('[ ,.]+$', '', tolower(pub$author))

## Make edgelist by repeating 1st elements each length(vector)-1L
adjlist <- strsplit(coauthors, '\\s*,\\s*')
edgelist <- cbind(
    unlist(lapply(adjlist, tail, -1L)),                        # col1
    rep(sapply(adjlist, `[`, 1L), times=lengths(adjlist)-1L)   # col2
)

## make graph
g <- graph_from_edgelist(edgelist, directed=FALSE)

## Offset labels a bit: nodes printed from +x-axis counter-clockwise
ord <- V(g)                                               # node order
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi-2*pi/length(ord), 2*pi/length(ord))  # angle
theta[theta>pi] <- -(2*pi - theta[theta>pi])              # convert to [0, pi]
dists <- rep(c(1, 0.7), length.out=length(ord))           # alternate distance

## Plot
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, vertex.label.degree=-theta, 
     vertex.label.dist=dists, vertex.label.cex=1.1,
     vertex.size=14, vertex.color='#FFFFCC', edge.color='#E25822')
```

[image]

#### Update

That error is coming from trying to give a negative `times` argument (ie. when one of the elements in your list contains no authors).

To add-self loops and remove zero character entries that occur in the new query you need to first filter the coauthor list to only contain entries with characters, then repeat those elements that are length==1 in the adjlist.  The rest should be the same.

```
scurl <- "scholar.google.com/citations?user=xqefLxQAAAAJ&hl=en"
citid <- regmatches(scurl, gregexpr('(?<=user=)[[:alnum:]]+', scurl, perl=TRUE))
pub <- get_publications(citid, flush=TRUE)

## tolower does character conversion, and remove the trailing "..."
coauthors <- sub('[ ,.]+$', '', tolower(pub$author))
coauthors <- coauthors[nzchar(coauthors)]  # only keep entries that aren't blank

## Add self-loops for single-author entries
adjlist <- strsplit(coauthors, '\\s*,\\s*')
lens <- lengths(adjlist)
adjlist[lens==1L] <- lapply(adjlist[lens==1L], rep, times=2)  # repeat single author entries
```

Then continue as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the same issue is happening again, it works fine with small number of publications (like the google scholar profile you have used), for example if you use these two profiles that have lots of publications (
# prof snijders
scurl <- "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=xqefLxQAAAAJ&hl=en"
# prof Welman google scholar link as an example that gives the above error
scurl <- "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=_q2NODAAAAAJ&hl=en"
)
then error happen again:
Error in rep(sapply(adjlist, `[`, 1L), times = lengths(adjlist) - 1L) : 
  invalid 'times' argument

Comment: and, is it possible not to remove one-author (single author) papers ? to copy it in both columns and have a loop in the graph ? this way it is possible to compare them with multi author papers number and give some insights ... by the way, I am going to publish it as a shiny app soon, but I cannot install dyplr and scholar packages on my amazon instance because of little RAM (1 GB).

Comment: I forgot to mention your name in two above comments. I will be grateful to hear your idea how to solve it
@slickrickulicious

Comment: thanks for your update, it is working like a charm now, but  there is a slightly small problem in your method of extracting the google scholar ID of the person from url, you should remove the part after & (including it as well), I was using this line to do that:
citid <- strsplit((strsplit(scurl,"&",fixed = TRUE)[[1]][1]),"=",fixed = TRUE)[[1]][2]

Thanks again for your great help, now self loops and empty author fields seems to work too :)
@slickrickulicious

Comment: working with the same data as this question (that I have asked before), I have problem with some author names with differents initials, means in case of some authors in google scholar, there are more than one spelling for same person, e.g "sm iacus" and "s iacus" who are same person, any idea how I can find that they are same and replace one with another (with most popular name spelling probably) ? it causes the resulting network to have 2 nodes for similar person :(